# React Native ios 0x8badf00d error

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm developing audio streaming ios application using react-native, but have a problem that app is restarted after staying in lock screen mode more than 10 minutes.

For example, click the start button for audio, then back to lock screen mode when audio streaming is starting, then wait 10 minutes more after audio streaming is finish. then when I click App to back again, App is restarted again(Start from the very beginning of app with launch screen.)

Moreover, even lock screen mode, when audio streaming is on playing(like 20 mins..), this issue has not happened. Only it has happened when I wait more than 10 minutes in lock screen mode after "audio streaming is finished" or "I paused streaming".

The problem is it's ok with simulator or device connection with simulator but has a problem after test flight.

I have searched a lot and found some similar topic, but all solution is by swift or objective-c. As a beginner of mobile development, I can't solve this problem with that.

So please let me know if there is a way to solve this problem by javascript code.

Here is my app device log.

```html
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace <0xF>, Code 0x8badf00d
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000018636f224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000018636f09c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000187340e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                 0x000000018733eae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                 0x000000018726eda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   GraphicsServices               0x0000000188cd8074 GSEventRunModal + 100
6   UIKit                          0x000000018d529058 UIApplicationMain + 208
7   MaboProject                    0x0000000100044540 main (main.m:18)
8   libdyld.dylib                  0x000000018627d59c start + 4
```

Thanks